# Windows losing focus on Gnome on Fedora 17

Tags: fedora, gnome, x11, window-management

I have a problem using Gnome on Fedora 17 where, after a period of time, I cannot regain focus on any windows; that is, I can only see the desktop screen. If I Alt-Tab I can see the other windows, but if I try to switch to them it immediately  goes back to desktop. My usual solution is to log out and log back in, which fixes the problem.

Any advice?

*Edit*: Ctrl-Alt-Left/Right does not do anything. If I do Crtl-Alt-Up/Down to move to another desktop it still does the same thing.

*Edit 2*: I can now replicate the problem, and it always occurs when Alt-Tabbing. I've disabled the "Coverflow Alt-Tab" extension; if I don't get it again, I guess there is a bug in this extension

Comment: What desktop environment or window manager are you using?

Comment: If you use `Ctrl + Alt + Left Arrow` and then `Ctrl + Alt + Right Arrow` does that fix it?

Comment: @Gilles: Gnome 3.4.1

Comment: @slm: Thanks, I'll try that when it happens next. Interesting to note that, although I can't see anything but the desktop, anything I type does actually work (i.e. even though I can't see the terminal, typing 'firefox' does load Firefox)